# Most elegant implementation of enumerable static class filed in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the method `buildErrorMessage`, the value of parameter `errorType` must be some value of `ErrorMessagesBuilder.ERROR_TYPES` value. Of course, this problem could be solved if to define type alias or something like this outside the class. Is there more elegant solution, completely encapsulated in `ErrorMessagesBuilder`?

```
export default class ErrorMessagesBuilder {

  public static ERROR_TYPES: {[propertyName: string]: string} = {
    REQUIRED_PARAMETER_ABSENCE: 'Required parameter absence',
    INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: 'Invalid parameter value'
  };

  public static buildErrorMessage(
      {
        errorType,
        // ...
      } : {
        errorType: /* Any value of ErrorMessagesBuilder.ERROR_TYPES  */
        // ...
      }): string
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the enum outside of the class and expose it with a static member. Hope this fits your use case. Otherwise i do not see a better way of solving your problem.

[FIDDLE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=6&pln=1&pc=17#code/KYOwrgtgBAogSnA8nA+gFQJoAUYGUoDeAsAFBRRwwCKAqgJKUAiKWAgnKwLIxrwqsAhXDAByAYRhQAvFABEcYAEcwASwBOwACZQADgEM1eiMAAuwNVD0AjAM6gAxsFkAaUuToiAaqwAydZmwc3Lyo3j40kjKydCAAbnoANira+obGZhbxCWBOpAC+ANykpMAAHjoA9momUJrAAGZ6YAk19gl6NjawampVnMCdegDmAwKqCXUWxGS6YFZJ9lA2JnomKovwSKiYOPgym8jo2HhFJG6z8+tLK2uLVuOaMD19AzbDwAAU0+Tk5r1qaAAnjpgOc8gAuQjnX7PAHA4CQg7bY64U7kPIASkhsQqyShM3IAHpCVAAHTksH5YokJ7-fqDEY2MYqCbmUn3FmPWH0t4jL7QqB-KpAkGI7mvd5Mh5spFHXakjxhfwsdhcHh8MIRfIYoA)

```
enum ERROR_TYPES {
  REQUIRED_PARAMETER_ABSENCE = "Required parameter absence",
  INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE = "Invalid parameter value"
};

export default class ErrorMessagesBuilder {
  public static ERROR_TYPES = ERROR_TYPES;

  public static buildErrorMessage({
    errorType
  }: {
    errorType: ERROR_TYPES;
  }): void {
    // ...
  }
}

ErrorMessagesBuilder.buildErrorMessage({
    errorType: ErrorMessagesBuilder.ERROR_TYPES.INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If your solution is the best that TypeScript allows, your answer is perfect.